# Help identify waterproof tactile button cap

Tags: switches, identification, button, environmental-sealing

I’ve been searching for a special kind of tactile button cap that mounts to a panel and effectively makes it splash-proof, while still allowing the button beneath to be used. I’ve seen it on motorcycles, but haven’t found what it is called.

They look really handy for projects that don’t require a full custom key panel and they’re a lot smaller than screw-in waterproof buttons. They are mounting in the housing itself and transfer the push down to a PCB-mounted tactile switch.

Has anyone seen them before and maybe know what they are called?

[image: Button panel with three rubber caps, one partly removed]

*Figure 1: Button panel with three rubber caps, one partly removed*

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You're allowed ask what they're called but not where to buy. Please take the [Tour].

Comment: No, but if you search digikey there are plenty of waterproof switches

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/tactile-switches/197?gclid=Cj0KCQjwl9GCBhDvARIsAFunhslRLVTqMmx1YuJ3gA3rZeulIkgjlueNTmEKPhKFiJAPtOdD-NW406gaArQQEALw_wcB&s=N4IgjCBcoGwJwHYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iAMwCsccVSxVMADKzDCM22IyAF1iABwAuUEAGVRAJwCWAOwDmIAL6riAJgogA7plH4ZwmSRLoABLl1zRKABaDVQA&utm_adgroup=General&utm_campaign=EN_Product_Switches_MBR&utm_content=General&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_term=%2Bwaterproof%20%2Bswitch  The switches above look like they are custom and use a non-waterproof switch with a custom cover